# How to configure Jersey EntityFilteringFeature running on Payara 5

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, entity, filtering

I'm trying to configure Jersey EntityFiltering for my application running on Payara 5. I followed the Jersey documentation https://docs.huihoo.com/jersey/2.13/entity-filtering.html#d0e13181 but even when I'm running the example project I can't reach my REST services.

I configured the jersey EntityFiltering on my application but when I register the EntityFilteringFeature (register(EntityFilteringFeature.class);) as shown in the documentation, I can't reach all of my REST services (HTTP 404 returned). If I comment the register line, I can reach the service (but without use of EntityFiltering). 
I tried to run the example project (https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/2.13/examples/entity-filtering) but I have exactly the same problem...

Do I have something to configure on Payara ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

**EDIT :**

Below is the code for my app (same as the jersey example) :

ResourceConfig configuration class :

```
package my.app.entity.filtering;

import my.app.entity.filtering.filtering.ProjectDetailedView;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.filtering.EntityFilteringFeature;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

/**
 * Entity Filtering application.
 *
 */
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class EntityFilteringApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public EntityFilteringApplication() {
        // Register all resources present under the package.
        packages("my.app.entity.filtering.filtering");
        property(EntityFilteringFeature.ENTITY_FILTERING_SCOPE, new Annotation[] 
{ProjectDetailedView.Factory.get()});
        // Entity Data Filtering feature.
        // Here is the line which makes my App doesn't work
        register(EntityFilteringFeature.class);

    }

}
```

Here are my entityfiltering classes (all are in the package my.app.entity.filtering.filtering) :

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@EntityFiltering
public @interface ProjectDetailedView {

    /**
     * Factory class for creating instances of {@code ProjectDetailedView} annotation.
     */
    public static class Factory extends AnnotationLiteral<ProjectDetailedView> implements ProjectDetailedView {

        private Factory() {
        }

        public static ProjectDetailedView get() {
            return new Factory();
        }
    }
}

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@EntityFiltering
public @interface TaskDetailedView {

    /**
     * Factory class for creating instances of {@code TaskDetailedView} annotation.
     */
    public static class Factory extends AnnotationLiteral<TaskDetailedView> implements TaskDetailedView {

        private Factory() {
        }

        public static TaskDetailedView get() {
            return new Factory();
        }
    }
}

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@EntityFiltering
public @interface UserDetailedView {

    /**
     * Factory class for creating instances of {@code UserDetailedView} annotation.
     */
    public static class Factory extends AnnotationLiteral<UserDetailedView> implements UserDetailedView {

        private Factory() {
        }

        public static UserDetailedView get() {
            return new Factory();
        }
    }
}
```

The Entity classes : Project.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Project {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ProjectDetailedView
    private List<Task> tasks;

    @ProjectDetailedView
    private List<User> users;

    public Project() {
    }

    public Project(final Long id, final String name, final String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(final List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(final List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

Task.java :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Task {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @TaskDetailedView
    private Project project;

    @TaskDetailedView
    private User user;

    public Task() {
    }

    public Task(final Long id, final String name, final String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(final String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(final Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(final User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

User.java :

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    private List<Project> projects;

    private List<Task> tasks;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(final Long id, final String name, final String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(final String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @UserDetailedView
    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(final List<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    @UserDetailedView
    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(final List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```

The resource class (I post just one) : ProjectResource.java :

```
@Path("projects")
@Produces("application/json")
public class ProjectsResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    public Project getProject(@PathParam("id") final Long id) {
        return getDetailedProject(id);
    }

    @GET
    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return getDetailedProjects();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("detailed/{id}")
    public Project getDetailedProject(@PathParam("id") final Long id) {
        return EntityStore.getProject(id);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("detailed")
    public List<Project> getDetailedProjects() {
        return EntityStore.getProjects();
    }
}
```

And the class EntityStore.java which is used to get some data :

```
@SuppressWarnings({"JavaDoc", "UnusedDeclaration"})
public final class EntityStore {

    private static final Map<Long, Project> projects = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Project>();
    private static final Map<Long, User> users = new LinkedHashMap<Long, User>();
    private static final Map<Long, Task> tasks = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Task>();

    static {
        // Projects.
        final Project project = createProject("Jersey", "Jersey is the open source (under dual CDDL+GPL license) JAX-RS 2.0 " +
                "(JSR 339) production quality Reference Implementation for building RESTful Web services.");

        // Users.
        final User robot = createUser("Jersey Robot", "very@secret.com");

        // Tasks.
        final Task filtering = createTask("ENT_FLT", "Entity Data Filtering");
        final Task oauth = createTask("OAUTH", "OAuth 1 + 2");

        // Project -> Users, Tasks.
        add(project, robot);
        filtering.setProject(project);
        oauth.setProject(project);

        // Users -> Projects, Tasks.
        add(robot, project);
        filtering.setUser(robot);
        oauth.setUser(robot);

        // Tasks -> Projects, Users.
        add(filtering, project);
        add(oauth, project);
        add(filtering, robot);
        add(oauth, robot);
    }

    public static void add(final Project project, final User user) {
        user.getProjects().add(project);
    }

    public static void add(final User user, final Project project) {
        project.getUsers().add(user);
    }

    public static void add(final Task task, final User user) {
        user.getTasks().add(task);
    }

    public static void add(final Task task, final Project project) {
        project.getTasks().add(task);
    }

    public static Project createProject(final String name, final String description) {
        return createProject(name, description, null, null);
    }

    public static Project createProject(final String name, final String description, final List<User> users,
                                        final List<Task> tasks) {
        final Project project = new Project(projects.size() + 1l, name, description);

        project.setTasks(tasks == null ? new ArrayList<Task>() : tasks);
        project.setUsers(users == null ? new ArrayList<User>() : users);
        projects.put(project.getId(), project);

        return project;
    }

    public static User createUser(final String name, final String email) {
        return createUser(name, email, null, null);
    }

    public static User createUser(final String name, final String email, final List<Project> projects, final List<Task> tasks) {
        final User user = new User(users.size() + 1l, name, email);

        user.setProjects(projects == null ? new ArrayList<Project>() : projects);
        user.setTasks(tasks == null ? new ArrayList<Task>() : tasks);
        users.put(user.getId(), user);

        return user;
    }

    public static Task createTask(final String name, final String description) {
        return createTask(name, description, null, null);
    }

    public static Task createTask(final String name, final String description, final Project project, final User user) {
        final Task task = new Task(tasks.size() + 1l, name, description);

        task.setProject(project);
        task.setUser(user);
        tasks.put(task.getId(), task);

        return task;
    }

    public static Project getProject(final Long id) {
        return projects.get(id);
    }

    public static User getUser(final Long id) {
        return users.get(id);
    }

    public static Task getTask(final Long id) {
        return tasks.get(id);
    }

    public static List<Project> getProjects() {
        return new ArrayList<Project>(projects.values());
    }

    public static List<User> getUsers() {
        return new ArrayList<User>(users.values());
    }

    public static List<Task> getTasks() {
        return new ArrayList<Task>(tasks.values());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add the code for your EntityFiltering, your JAX-RS configuration, your JAX-RS endpoint, and other related code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the answer.

The documentation says :

19.8. Modules with support for Entity Data Filtering
List of modules from Jersey workspace that support Entity Filtering:

MOXy

Jackson (2.x)

In order to use Entity Filtering in mentioned modules you need to explicitly register either EntityFilteringFeature, SecurityEntityFilteringFeature or SelectableEntityFilteringFeature to activate Entity Filtering for particular module.

So I tried to register JacksonFeature.class with the EntityFilteringFeature.class and it is working now.
I think it was not working before since Yasson is now the default JSON-B provider in JEE.